# Segmentation fault with recursive factorial implementation

Tags: c

Now I am practicing using Vim on Linux.
I made a simple code like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int n){
   if (n<0) { return 0; }
   else if (n==0) { return 1; }
   else { return n * factorial(n); }
}

int main(void){
   int n = 0;

   printf("Put n value : ");
   scanf("%d", &n);  /* non-OP inserted ";" to help people focus on the problem */

   printf("%d! = %d\n", n, factorial(n));

   return 0;
}
```

When I put -1 and 0, it works. They return 0 and 1.
However, when I put positive integer values on n, it didn't work.
I tried to find out the reason so I used gdb,
but it just said like this :

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x0000000000400620 in factorial ()

What's wrong with my code? I even cannot understand the point.

Comment: The [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) don't happen in `vim` or in the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler but in your own faulty code. You could have used a different [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (like [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) or a different compiler (like [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)...), and still get the same error. So the `vim` tag (or mention of it) is irrelevant

Comment: The close vote as "typo or not reproducable" is something to be explained...

Comment: The close vote as "no description no mcve" is somethign to be explained...

Comment: Next time, compile your code with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and improve the code to get no warnings. Then you could much more easily [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). BTW your *fix-my-code* question is off-topic (without any tentative explanation from your part)

Comment: @user3386109 Of course.

Comment: @Yunnosch This *is* a [mental typo question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313884/closing-as-a-mental-typo) - however, it *is* likely to help future readers so it can be considered on-topic.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Nice link, read it. Agree with both your aspects.

Comment: Readability is one of many reasons why you should avoid recursion. Writing this as a loop had been much faster and very trivial. Instead you write code that you don't even understand yourself. Don't use recursion if you can avoid it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `n > 0` your recursive program never terminates. The value of `n` is never decremented and so it continues running recursively until your run out of memory.

It should be `return n * factorial(n-1);`

Answer (score 3):

You code is causing stack overflow. In the given function `n` is never decremented. Last statement should be

```
else { return n * factorial(n-1); }
```